# How should I serialize JPA entity to JSON format

Tags: java, json, rest, jpa

I have the following data hierarchy

User:

```
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("sub")
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String fraction;

    private Integer points;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn (name="population_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Population population;

}
```

Population:

```
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Population {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private int total;

    private int builder;

    private int scientist;
    private int resources;

    @OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "population")
    private User user;

}
```

And here is my controller method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/account/accountInfo")
    public String getAccountInfo(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authorization) throws JsonProcessingException {
        User userInfo = userService.getUserInfo(authorization);
        User userAllInfo = gameService.getUser(userInfo.getId());
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(userAllInfo);
    }
```

However when I do a request on that enpoint I receive:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
```

I wonder if should I change a model to not be bidirectional or maybe there is some option on serialization?
What should I change to make it working?

Comment: You can mark one of the fields (either `user` or `population`) with `@JsonIgnore`

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have User in Population and vice versa, I think you can put @JsonIgnore on User in Population.